# Rand() returns same value; in a hidden input

Tags: php

For some reason if I try to assign a value to my input type hidden then I always get the same value (1), I can assign a value to it with javascript but not php..:

```
<?php
 $num = rand(1, 4);                     
?>  

 <?php echo $num; ?><?php echo $num; ?><?php echo $num; ?>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num; ?>" name="catch_num1">
```

If rand gave 4 this would give 444 but in input type it would always give value="1"??

It seems like a bug to me but I'm checking all my code in between.

Comment: I just ran your code, and it actually did give me different values each time, like you want it to. (PHP 5.3.6) Odd...

Comment: Ya I cannot see anything wrong here either. Some tips though. Don't forget to close your `input` tags like `<input type="hidden" value="2" />`. And you could shorten the `echo $num;` by doing `<?=$num?>`.

Comment: And another tip `echo str_repeat($num, 3)`.

Comment: It's literally started working after I've only changed the position of value and name????

Comment: @Jules <?= if short tags are disabled in php.ini.

Comment: I just tried changing it back and it works like the way it was before (PHP 5.3.5) Trippy.

Comment: @Jules - Short tags are bad and are not supported in all environments.  That's why its better to get ahead and avoid them just to be safe.

Comment: @RobB - They are not bad. They are commonly used by many php developers, including myself. They might not be activated in php.ini on 1 out of 100.000 webservers, but I haven't seen any yet. They are way easier and faster to use and makes your code better readable.

Comment: @Jules - Sorry that was late last night and perhaps "bad" was not the most appropriate adjective to be used.  I personally always used them until I came to a client that did not have it available, at which point I started avoiding them.

Answer (score 1):

Might be you set constant value to https://www.php.net/srand in prior to calling `rand`.

Comment: `Note: As of PHP 4.2.0, there is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is now done automatically.`

Comment: Yes, but if the OP is using it wrong, it might cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be. `rand(min, max)` *always* gives value between the *min* and the *max*.

Have you tried `rand(4, 14)`? does it give you 1 too? are you sure you echo the `$_POST` value that actually IS this one and not another?

Try using [`mt_rand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Edit: well, I have found lots of results of the same problem. But each got its own reason.

If you're using Firefox for example, refresh using CTRL+F5 to omit cache. The random number might have been stored in cache or something?!